# What is the purpose of the point system in online divisions?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-series, pro-evolution-soccer-2016

I've been playing PES 2016 for a few days and there are a couple of things about online division that confuse me a bit:

1. Does the division you're in have any effect for matchmaking? It seems to me that matchmaking is mainly about your rating and there is no indication that the opponent's division is taken into account. In fact I'm now in division 6 but I still sometimes get opponents from division 12... Because when I was familiarizing myself with game mechanics I lost a few games in a row and my rating is relatively low. If divisions are not important for matchmaking then what's the purpose of its existence after all. Only for the player to set a target for himself?
2. The points required to advance to the next division seems quite ridiculously high... I was playing with Belgium in the beginning but then when I was trying to advance from division 7 to 6 today, I saw I needed 2500 points... which is quite hard for Belgium (396 points per game), so I switched to Sweden. Now to advance from division 6 to 5 I need 3000 points. It gets me wondering, how all those RM/Barca/Bayern users ever advance divisions after all. Or do they simply not care about it? And what's the point of setting such a high bar for promotion. In fact in the worldwide ranking I see even the best players seem to be only in division 4.

Comment: @pinckerman Can you at least explain the reason for editing the tags? I don't see how it's a problem to have both `pes-2016` and `pro-evolution-soccer` as tags. Some knowledgable user might not be subscribed to the newest iteration of the game but is still subscribed to the franchise in general. Consecutive editing without any explanation is **rude** to say the very least.

Comment: Imho `pro-evolution-soccer` tag should be used only for general question about the series, you are asking about a specific one. For the same reason if you ask a question about Fifa16 it doesn't need a generic `Fifa` tag. If you find the original tag useful you are free to rollback, I didn't mean to be rude.

Comment: @pinckerman The online divisions system is in use not only for this iteration of the game in the same sense that the "seasons" and "ultimate team" modes did not just appear overnight in FIFA 16, so I don't see how it's specific to PES 2016. The fact that I happen to play PES 2016 doesn't mean this is an issue unique to this installation. Please, if you have no knowledge about the game don't arbitrarily perform such edits.

Comment: I have knowledge about the site, and `pro-evolution-soccer` tag probably was added to address the first Pro Evolution Soccer (Winning Eleven 5). So using it for a PES2016 question would be wrong anyway.

Comment: @pinckerman That game is more than 10 years old... Whatever. The important thing is hopefully somebody would see and answer this question.

Comment: That's why that tag is hard to identify now. Anyway I don't see many people playing PES here...